# How do you find the enthalpy of solution of a hydrated salt?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics

I am doing an experiment in school where I try to find how heating time affects the enthalpy of solution of a salt in water. I take a hydrated salt ($\ce{Na_2CO_3 \cdot 10H_2O }$), heat it for a certain amount of time (say 2 minutes) and then measure the enthalpy of solution of the salt.

Lets say after 2 minutes the fully hydrated salt turns partially hydrated (say $\ce{Na_2CO_3 \cdot 10H_{2}O ->  Na_2CO_3 \cdot 8H_2O})$. I know that for the solution enthalpy of solution of an anhydrous salt, I can find it out by adding the lattice enthalpy of the salt and the hydration enthalpy. But for hydrated and partially hydrated salts (such as  $\ce{Na_2CO_3 \cdot 8H_2O}$) how do you find the enthalpy of solution in water?

Comment: $\ce{Na2CO3·8H2O}$ does not exist. After heating $\ce{Na2CO3·10H2O}$, you will obtain the anhydrous salt $\ce{Na2CO3}$.

Comment: @Maurice, so when I heat 10 gm of $\ce{Na_2CO_3 \cdot 10H_2O}$, and lose 2 grams I get some proportion of anhydrous salt and some proportion of the fully hydrated salt?

Comment: @ Prasad.. Yes. If you only lose $20$% of the initial weight, it means that the déshydratation is not finished. The lost should be about  $63$% of the weight of the initial amount of $\ce{Na2CO3·10H2O}$

Comment: Why do you not record the thermogram while dissolving a known quantity of the water free form / the hydrated form for calorimetry and then apply [Hess' law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hess%27s_law)?  If your lab financially walks on a shoe string, a coffee cup calorimeter may help you to save some bucks ([2017JChemEduc494](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acs.jchemed.6b00189), or open access [2020Heliyon03591](https://www.cell.com/heliyon/fulltext/S2405-8440(20)30436-9?_returnURL=https%3A%2F%2Flinkinghub.elsevier.com%2Fretrieve%2Fpii%2FS2405844020304369%3Fshowall%3Dtrue#secd10738034)).

Comment: @Buttonwood could you give an example? I'm not following. One equation would be $\ce{Na_2CO_3 \cdot 5H_2O -> Na_2CO_3 \cdot 10H_2O}$ (which does exist), but what would the other 2 equations be?

Comment: @Maurice that is exactly, what I am trying to find. If it is heated for 2 min, and 20% of the mass is lost, what would the enthalpy be. (Perhaps I should have worded it as the effect of water of crystallization on enthalpy of solution).

Comment: @prasadpradyumna The lower part of http://www.docbrown.info/page07/delta1Hc.htm showcases with section 7 and 8 the determination of enthalpies of hydration for $\ce{CuSO4 . 5 H2O}$ and $\ce{MgSO4 . 7 H2O}$ for with already determined enthalpies of solution of these, as well as their anhydrous analogues.

Comment: @Buttonwood thanks for the link. Will try out

Comment: @ Prasad. Why do you heat only 2 minutes ? It should last much longer !

Comment: @Maurice I will do it for longer. 2 min was just an example

Comment: @ Prasad.. The heats of solution of sodium carbonate and its decahydrate are taken from an old edition of the Handbook of Physics and Chemistry. Editions from $2002$ and later do not give these values. But in the old edition $1961$, the heats of solution of sodium carbonates (with or without water) are given, in kilocalories per mole. Transformed into kilojoule per mole, the heat of dissolution of the anhydrous salt is $23.6$ kJ/mol. For the decahydrate, it is - $67.6$ kJ/mol. The heats of formation are - $4085.2$ kJ/mol for the decahydrate, and -$1132$ kJ/mol for the anhydrous salt

Comment: @Maurice thanks for that. I'll use it in my calculations